# Arduino Measuring Microwave Leakage

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, electronics

I want to measure if my microwave has a leakage using Arduino. Ideally, I would like to get the exact number measured by mW/cm2 (similar to HT-M2 devices). Any advice which Arduino module can do it?

Comment: No Arduino can do it. Instead a microwave detector will do it, and the Arduino will control it and process the data.

Comment: @Majenko, that's what the OP asked. "Any advice which Arduino module can do it?". They are looking for Arduino compatible components that will measure microwave radiation. Personally, I have no idea if there are microwave measurement devices that have serial interfaces that are easy to connect to an Arduino. I will say that a quick search on `HT-M2` revealed dedicated Microwave leakage detectors for less than $15 US. You're not going to compete with that.

Comment: @Davithbul, post a link to a microwave detector datasheet and someone here will be able to tell you if the detector is arduino compatible

Comment: @DuncanC you are right price wise HT-M2 is not expensive, but for my use case, I need to monitor constantly using some microcontroller - Arduino or Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @jsotola I was not able to find the datasheet for HT-M2, but I will still look for it. Thank you for advice.

Comment: you asked about a module that can be used with an Arduino ... the HT-M2 is not a module, it is a self contained device

Comment: @jsotola Right, I meant maybe it would be possible to understand which exact module does HT-M2 use and use the same module to connect from Arduino.

Comment: it probably does not use a standalone module that you could extract from the device ... it probably contains a "front end" of a radio receiver ... just an antenna, a tuned circuit and a demodulator ... the output of the circuit is a voltage level that varies with signal strength